# How do I get the outputs of a Gradle artifact transform?

Tags: java, gradle, java-module, artifact

Gradle has [a sample](https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_java_modules_with_transform.html) showing how a custom plugin can be used to convert legacy JARs into Java 9+ modules. I've adapted it into my own build and now I would like to use the generated modules with JLink to produce a custom JRE image. However, I don't know how to get the path of each generated artifact in my custom `jlink` task. Does Gradle add the result of artifact transforms as dependencies somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. At least for the sample provided by the Gradle team, the transformed artifacts become part of the `runtimeClasspath` configuration. So here's how I build the module path:

```
def javaHome = System.getProperty("java.home")
def modulePath = ["libs", [javaHome, "jmods"].join(File.separator)]
project.configurations.runtimeClasspath.each { f->
    if (!modulePath.contains(f.absolutePath)) {
        modulePath.add(f.absoluteFile.parent)
    }
}
```